# How to run Custom Javascript code in specific page of codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have Model Box which I want to open on a specific page of the codeigniter page (**How it work**).

In My View, the following code is for the model box:

```
<!-- Model -->
<div class="modal" id="how_its_modal" role="dialog" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                
                <h4 class="modal-title">How Its Work Video</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <iframe width="100%" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DIx_xxxxx">
                </iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
    $custom_js = "$('#how_its_modal').modal('show');";
    //$custom_js = "This is okay";
?>
```

In my Controller, the following code:

```
public function privacy_policy()
    {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('privacy-policy');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
    public function help_center()
    {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('help-center');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
    public function how_it_works()
    {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('how-it-works');
        $this->load->view('footer', ['custom_js' => $custom_js]);
    }
    public function mart()
    {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('mart');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
```

So here I have multiple pages. So now I want to run the following code in only the how_it_works function means on the page **How it Works**.

```
<script>
    $('#how_its_modal').modal('show')
</script>
```

My Footer Code

```
<script src="<?php echo SITE_PATH; ?>/front/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo SITE_PATH; ?>/front/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo SITE_PATH; ?>/front/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo SITE_PATH; ?>/front/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo SITE_PATH; ?>/front/js/aos.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/10.16.0/sweetalert2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<?php echo $custom_js; ?>
<?php if(isset($custom_js)) { ?>
    <script><?php echo $custom_js; ?></script>
<?php }else{
    echo "Nothing Run";
} ?>
```

I can not put this script in the footer because if I will put then it will run on all pages which I do not want.

Comment: @Marleen I checked, But I do not want to make separate .js file for this tiny code.

Comment: @Marleen, I have tried this also, But it is showing an error undefined variable.

Comment: Now it is showing me blank means value is showing empty.

Answer (score 0):

You do with a particular class like you can check your current class and match it like this

if ($this->router->fetch_class() == 'YOUR CLASS NAME'){'Your script}

Comment: Sorry @soham, I did not get your point. Can you explain to me with code, How can I do this? I want to run my specific JS code on my particular page. if I write the JS code for one page, that code should not be run on another page.

Comment: You can just add one code in your footer

Comment: just assume i want to add on js in only my home page so i will check this if($this->router->fetch_class() == 'Home'){ here is my js}
home is my controller in this controller I have a home page so this condition check that if my class is home it's executing else it not

Comment: put this code in the footer, not in page

Answer (score -1):

Why you not try to put your script modal inside your page `how-it-works`? then move your jquery to header.
easy, but it's better you make one view for modal so you have.

```
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('help-center');
$this->load->view('footer');
$this->load->view('modal');
```

Comment: Thanks, @feri but For a single script, I should make a new view. Actually, I do not want to make a new view for tiny code.